# In/after hours. What preposition to use?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

> In/after 3 hours I will go to work.

I will have to go to work after 3 hours from now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, it is idiomatic (in all the varieties of English that I know) to use "in" with a length of time if the temporal focus is now, and "after" if the temporal focus is some other time (or there isn't one, so this is a timeless or habitual context).

So

> *In three hours I will go to work.*

normally means "from now".

> *After three hours I will go to work*

means "from some other time", presumably already established or referred to. It is probably in the future, but could even be in the past, for example: "I said I'd stay in for a while, when he left earlier. After three hours I'll go to work" means three hours after he left).

Answer (score 0):

I will go to work in three hours (implied: from now). 
Or: 
I will have to go to work three hours from now. 
/I will have to go to work AFTER three hours/ means there is another situation occuring and after that you will have to go to work. But the situation is not occuring now in the present.

/After three hours from now/ is not really grammatical in English.